# Bad Access in `top_level_code` when I set instance variable

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

Ok, this is an odd error and it's taken me many hours to track down the exact location (although the cause remains unknown).  The error *only* occurs on 64-bit devices.  In other words, it works fine on my iPhone 5, but crashes on my iPhone 6 Plus.

Essentially, I have a private variable in a class:

```
class Manager {
   private lastUpdated:NSDate?
}
```

Initially, it's not set.  This class retrieves messages from a server and then sets the `lastUpdated` variable to `NSDate()`.

```
  private func checkForNewMessages(complete:Result<[Message]> -> ()) {
      self.server.userMessages(u, fromDate: self.lastUpdated) { result in
        result.onSuccess { messages in
          self.insertMessages(messages)
          self.lastUpdated = NSDate()
          complete(Result(messages))
        }
        result.onError { err in complete(Result(err)) }
      }
  }
```

*I've deleted extraneous code, but nothing inside the code path that's crashing (just stuff around it)*

Note: I'm using a `Result` enum.  For more info about this kind of enum, this article is pretty good at explaining it: [Error Handling in Swift](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/error-handling-in-swift).

The first time the manager retrieves messages, everything works fine and the `lastUpdated` value is set correctly.  If I then try to retrieve messages again, the app crashes when it tries to set `self.lastUpdated = NSDate()`.

I *can* get it to work if I delay the assignment by using GCD, `dispatch_after`.  But I don't want to do that.

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

### Update

- This is only occurring when I assign a NSDate. It's not occurring if I try to set another object type (`Int`, `Bool`, `String`) etc.
- The crash occurs if I change the stored variable to `NSTimeInterval` and attempt to set it from `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()`
- The crash occurs if I store an array of updates and attempt to simply append a new date to that array.
- The crash occurs if I attempt to set `lastUpdated` *before* the server is called rather than in the callback.
- The crash occurs if I wrap `NSDate` in another class.
- The crash occurs is I set `lastUpdated` in a background thread
- The crash doesn't occur if I `println(NSDate())` (removing the assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took me numerous hours but I finally figured it out.

This will be a little difficult to explain and I'm not certain I fully understand what is going on.  The error actually occurred in the `Server` class that was making the request.  It took the `lastUpdated` date, converted it to a string and then sent that up to the server.  The first run, there was no date, so no issue.  In the second run, it took the date and used a date formatter to convert it to a string.  However, I thought that `stringFromDate` returned an Optional.  It does not.  Normally, the compiler would warn me if I attempted to unwrap something that wasn't an option.  However, I use Swift's functional aspects to use Infix operators to unwrap and conditionally pass the unwrapped value to another function, which can then pass it's value on.  It allows me to chain unwraps together so I can avoid "nested if-let hell".

Very simple but powerful:

```
infix operator >>? { associativity left}
func >>? <U,T>(opt: T?, f: (T -> U?)) -> U? {
  if let x = opt {
    return f(x)
  }
  return nil
}
```

Note that the function must return an Optional. For some reason, the Swift compiler missed the fact that `stringFromDate` did not return an optional and so it didn't warn me.  I'm not sure why that is, it's certainly warned me before:

```
if let update = fromDate >>? self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate {
```

*This fails, but not immediately*

Unwrapping a non-optional value doesn't immediately result in a crash, error or anything apparently. I successfully used the date string to send and receive data from the server.  I'm not certain why unwrapping a non-optional string would later result in a crash and that *only* when I attempted to set the instance variable that of the backing NSDate object the string was generated from.  I think somehow, unwrapping a non-optional screwed up some pointers, but not necessarily the pointer to the unwrapped object. I think the crash itself has to do with Swift attempting to release or dealloc the original instance variable (`lastUpdated`) when a new one is set, but found the memory address messed up.  I think only a Apple Swift engineer could tell me what actually happened, but perhaps there are clues here to how Swift works internally.